# JavaScript regex to extract different parts of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-negation

This is an interesting one - I am looking for a JavaScript regex solution to extract different parts from a string. Any input is much appreciated.

Example -

```
";1XYZ123_UK;1;2.3;evt14=0.0|evt87=0.0,;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;evt14=0.0;fly;0;0;;;"
```

I am trying to extract just these bits from the string ignoring the rest-

```
“1XYZ123_UK;2;3;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;”
```

Basically extract anything starting with 1XYZ up until it encounters 'evt'.

Comment: Does it ALWAYS start with 1XY..?

Comment: ";1XYZ123_UK;1;2.3;evt14=0.0|evt87=0.0,;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;evt14=0.0".replace(/evt\d+=\d+\.\d+/g, '')

would return  ";1XYZ123_UK;1;2.3;|,;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;"

Comment: Lloyd - Yes, it always starts with 1XYZ but it can be anywhere in the string. Thanks.

Comment: If it's interesting you must tried something, don't you?

Comment: Felix - I did, test.match(/^(((?!evt).)*)((?=1XYZ).)*/g). Needed different solutions to see where I can improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = ';1XYZ123_UK;1;2e.3;evt14=0.0|evt87=0.0,;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;evt14=0.0';
var r = s.match(/1XYZ((?!evt).)*/g);
```

Will give you your desired strings:

```
["1XYZ123_UK;1;2e.3;", "1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s= ";1XYZ123_UK;1;2.3;evt14=0.0|evt87=0.0,;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;evt14=0.0"

s = s.replace(/(evt.+?(?:\||;|$))/g, "");

console.log(s) // ";1XYZ123_UK;1;2.3;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Almost there. One small query - What if the string contains more words - Example - ";1XYZ123_UK;1;2.3;evt14=0.0|evt87=0.0,;1XYZ456_UK;4;5.6;evt14=0.0;fly;0;0;;;"

Comment: please update your question with this scenario using syntax highlighting properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Use groups (`(...)`) to capture parts of the matched string. After a successful match the substrings captured can be accessed via the array returned from `String.match` or `Regex.exec`.

The first element of the array (index 0) is the whole match, the next (index 1) is the first capture.

Eg.

```
var re = /1XY(.*)evt/
var result = theString.match(re)
```

then, if there is a match (`result` is not null) then

```
result[0]
```

will be the whole match (starting `1XY` and ending `evt`) while

```
result[1]
```

will be the text between those strings.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I am using groups. Let me try your method.